# "are not prepared" or "haven't prepared"

Tags: word-usage, difference

> You are not prepared for the exam.
>
> You haven't prepared for the exam.

Which one is the right one?  Can someone explain in detail the differences if there are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first sentence, *prepared* is an adjective meaning *ready.*

In the second sentence, it is a verb - 'You have not made yourself ready for the exam'.

They are two different ways of saying the same thing; neither is more 'right' than the other.

Comment: Another way of putting it would be to say that the first describes your state; the second describes your omission, what you have failed to do.